# Parsing Perl 5 and examining the syntax tree

Tags: perl, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I've read and understood that it's not possible to parse Perl 5 code without a Perl interpreter because of the `BEGIN` blocks.

I know there are standalone parsers like
[`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI)
(used by [`Perl::Critic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic))
that approximately parses the initial document.

But I couldn't find any reference to the procedure for outputting some kind of
*abstract syntax tree*, or whatever internal structure resembling a tree that Perl uses for the *execution* phase.

It would be interesting to compare the internal representation for the parse and execution phases to see the code expand and change.

Comment: Take a look at the B::Concise module for example.

Comment: Apart from the [`B`](http://p3rl.org/B)/[`O`](http://p3rl.org/O) core modules, there was also [MAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perldelta.html#MAD) (unmaintained, meanwhile removed). Most software that parses Perl is either a source filter (breaks easily) or builds on [`PL_keyword_plugin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#PL_keyword_plugin) (robust, but limited). See [examples](https://grep.cpan.me/?q=PL_keyword_plugin).

Comment: @daxim, `PL_keyword_plugin` is actually problematic, and has been supplanted Devel::CallParser.

Comment: [It's not just because of the BEGIN blocks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44722)

Comment: @mob, It doesn't require Perl to parse prototypes, and `use` statements are `BEGIN` blocks too, so that link doesn't add anything new. /// That said, it's surely possible to modify opcode at run-time too. But does anyone do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically there are a few options:

1. For static analysis, use [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI), which has the downside of not processing Perl code at `BEGIN` blocks. This would be analogous to "parsing".
2. For dynamic analysis, use Use [B::Concise](https://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html) to get the internal opcodes used for execution. This would be analogous to "compiling" (to the Perl VM).
3. A combination of both would be using [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) to get Perl code of the internal representation (instead of VM opcodes), and then send it to [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) for building the tree.

**EDIT**: clarified point 3 based on comment. Still don't know a command that would expand imports and output a single big file (so that syntax extensions are resolved).

Comment: B::Deparse does evaluate BEGIN – it just takes the opcodes after parsing and renders them as Perl source code, whereas B::Concise renders them in a more direct notation. Note that both of these modules are pure-Perl, so you can take a peek at how they traverse the opcode structure. Perl opcodes are both an AST and VM instructions.

Comment: I thought it didn't because even at level 7, use statements still expanded to the mentioned blocks. Perhaps I was expecting a big file with everything resolved (like the output of the C preprocessor which expands `#include`).

Comment: Perl's multi-phase compilation model is very differen't from C's text-based preprocessor. It seems your actual problem (“How can I pack all used Perl modules into a single script?” or “Why does B::Deparse expand use statements like this?”) is very different from the problem in your question: “How can I examine Perl's syntax tree”. Can you perhaps ask a new question that explains your actual problem more clearly?

Comment: It was an analogy, I know it's more similar to syntax macros (LISP) rather than text substitutions. But the idea was: if Deparse still outputs those blocks then the rest of the code syntax could be changed by an imported module.
Obviously in a dynamic language with introspection there is no end to this, as a program could be evaluating any generated string during execution.
But I wanted to know if it was possible to get the code after the `BEGIN` processing phase in Perl form for a syntax tree. Does it make sense?